# How to send base64 image via email

Tags: php, image, email, base64, send

I'm trying to send emamil with base64 encoded image but it doesn't display the image - it just display empty `img` tag.

When I dump data before sending, it's fine and image is displayed but it doesn't send it.

Data looks like that:

```html
$data['body'] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">';
```

How should I send it via mail? Thanks!

Edited: I'm using Laravel 4.It's part of my code, the other data that I send is not included because it's much code and to be much clear:

```html
 $data['body'] = '<img src="data:image/png;base64,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">';
            }
Mail::send(
            "emails.clientApplication",
            $data,
            function($m) use ($data,$template,$subject) {
                $m->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                    ->from($template['from'],$template['from_name'])
                    ->subject($subject);

            }
        );
```

Edited: I tried in my view in this way:

```html
<img src="<?php echo $message->embedData( 'data:image/png;base64,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'
                            , 'test'); ?>">
```

but it doesn't display image source correct. It displays it in this way:

```html
<img src="?ui=2&amp;ik=4a88c48485&amp;view=fimg&amp;th=154f6eb487014c53&amp;attid=0.1&amp;disp=emb&amp;attbid=ANGjdJ_sfWCGDQdwP3L7Xo7Q2X_4JSZixu4cGp0Rlg-m6gXuB7PPGXA05FdeVJWW6MWJdFFD8A9WtTY5fnmHUUlCnOXJXlvjTJT7V6OOtjCxDkU-qNls88Z9jMDHygg&amp;sz=s0-l75-ft&amp;ats=1464431508586&amp;rm=154f6eb487014c53&amp;zw&amp;atsh=0" class="CToWUd">
```

Comment: can you please share your email code.

Comment: if the e-mail recipient is a gmail account, you must also attach all images as file :(

Comment: Yes, I'm trying to send it in gmail, but I have also tried to send it in another mail server and the same.

Comment: How to attach images as file as my image is base64 decoded?

Comment: Have you try: `file_put_contents(base64_encode(file_get_contents($imgPath)))`?

Comment: I'll try it. But why gmail filters base64 images and is there any way to send it?

Comment: But I don't have $imgPath, it is base64 encoded image.. I have image src .How to do that?

Comment: @mistery_girl did you find an answer to this? I am also having the same issue