# How to attach a Laravel blade view in mail

Tags: php, laravel, email, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm trying to attach a blade view when send mail. I'm using Laravel 4. I tried with this:

```
Mail::send(
    "emails.clientEmail",
    $data,
    function($message) use ($data,$template,$subject) {
        $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
            ->from($template['from'],$template['from_name'])
            ->subject($subject)
            ->attach(app_path().'/views/email.blade.php');
    }
);
```

But my view `email.blade.php` is in blade template and it doesn't display the html but code.

How should I send it and display as html?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you metioned you can use `attachData` and add rendered data like:

```
$renderedData = view('email')->render();

Mail::send(
        "emails.clientEail",
        $data,
        function($message) use ($data,$template,$subject) {
            $message->to($data['email'], $data['name'])
                ->from($template['from'],$template['from_name'])
                ->subject($subject)
                ->attachData($renderedData, 'name_of_attachment');
        }
    );
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it now. Where should I locate $filePath - in which directory it should be?

Comment: for example in `/{projectPath}/ storage/tmp`

Comment: Oh, in fact I can send html data that I get from database as template instead ov blade view. Maybe this is better solution, but in this case should I use - attachdata('my html here', 'name');

Comment: ...or of course put as a `$renderedData` the data from database as you want

Comment: I'll try it now. :) Thanks

Comment: I tried and html is send but it is not rendered as html. I tried this:` ->attachData('<h1>This is some text</h1><p>text here</p>', 'test');` Oh my mistake, I forgot extension -> test.html

Comment: Excuse me, do you know how to display base64 encoded image in email -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37497110/how-to-send-base64-image-via-email

Comment: It's detailed in the Laravel docs like Raw Data Attachments: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/mail#attachments